# EventCreate PowerShell vs VBScript .Run

Tags: powershell, vbscript

When I use EventCreate in PowerShell, with a custom log and using the name of the script as the source, the log is created, and the source is created if it hasn't already been used. So, this works

```
EVENTCREATE /T Error /ID 100 /L PxTools /SO PxTools.vbs /D "Px Error test"
```

as long as I have already created the PxTools log.

However, when I use EventCreate with .Run in a VBScript, I can't use /SO at all. So this doesn't work

```
strEvent = "EVENTCREATE /T Error /ID 100 /L PxTools /SO Event.vbs /D " & Chr(34) & "Damnit" & Chr(34) '/SO Event.vbs
objShell.Run strEvent, 0, False
```

Even if I have created the source with PowerShell previously. But, take out the /SO and it works. But in both cases I am running the exact same command line utility. The only difference is that the VBScript is not being run with elevated privileges, but again, I can create the source earlier, with elevated privileges in PS, and the VBS still fails to write.

Comment: `EVENTCREATE` **requires** administrator rights.

Comment: JosefZ, I can run the code above that works, without the /SO, as a standard user with no elevation, and it works. Is it just the custom source that requires being an admin? I am still confused about why it works WITH a custom source from PS, but fails when VBScript is calling EventCreate. Weird.